# What databases do I have permissions on

Tags: php, sql, mysql, permissions

How can I find what databases I have a minimum of read access to in either basic SQL, MySQL specific or in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a command in MySQL which can show you all of the permissions you have.  The command is:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

It will give you output similar to:

```
root@(none)~> show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION | 
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is documented at in the [manual here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can execute

`SHOW DATABASES;`

**Description**

`SHOW DATABASES;`to see what you have at least minimal access to. Are you looking for something more programmatic?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try connecting to the database with phps mysql_connect(...) will tell you quickly whether or not you have access.

Comment: That would only show weather or not I can connect to the database server with the given username and password, it will not show weather or not the user has write permissions on a specific database.